# Asset false statement to check if displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a test in selenium. I have defined all my webelements in a page object package.

I am calling the webelement to my test using S.getColumn().

getcolumn() gets the webelement of the column in the web table

```
  By column = By.xpath("//id[@type='column']");
  ..
  ..
  public WebElement getcolumn(){
  return driver.findElement(column)
  }
```

I need to check if the webelement is displayed or not in my test

I am using:`Assert.assertFalse(S.getColumn().isDisplayed());`

but it throwing error. How do I write it correctly

Comment: What is the error

Comment: We can't correct your code that you haven't shared. Please edit your question and add the relevant code, e.g. `S.getColumn()` and maybe other methods. You also need to add the error. You really need to take the time to simplify your code and investigate to narrow down the issue and then update your question with what you've found.

Comment: Also take a minute to properly format your question, especially the code. See the formatting help if you don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Asserting an element isn't present doesn't really work in selenium, you usually get an exception because it's trying to interact with an element that isn't present on the page. You haven't shared the full code or the actual error you get, but at a guess I'd say you most likely end up with a `NoSuchElementException` If this is the case you'd need to wrap the assertion in a try/catch looking for that exception. e.g.

```
try {
        Assert.assertFalse(S.getColumn().isDisplayed())
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        LOG.info("Element not displayed as expected")
    }
```

With this, you'd get an assertion failure if the element is present, as it's expecting it to be false. If the element isn't present, the exception would drop you into the catch where you can just log/print whatever message you want and the test can carry on

Comment: You can easily use something like `driver.findElements(...).size() == 0` to verify an element isn't present.

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple problems with your code.

First is a purely Java problem. Your method `getColumn()` returns `void`. That means when you call `S.getColumn()` it will always be `null`. Your method should probably be:

```
public WebElement getColumn() {
    return driver.findElement(column);
}
```

Second is a Selenium problem. When an element is not displayed - hidden - this can be achieved several different ways:

One way is that the element attributes (like opacity) are manipulated such that it truly is *not displayed*. In that case testing for `.isDisplayed()` is usually sufficient.

Another way is that the element can be *removed* from the DOM. In this case testing for `.isDisplayed()` will throw `NoSuchElementException`. To test in this situation you can use a `try..catch` block, something like:

```
boolean isDisplayed;
try {
    isDisplayed = S.getColumn().isDisplayed();
} catch(NoSuchElementException ignore) {
    isDisplayed = false;
} finally {
    Assert.assertTrue("element is NOT displayed!",
        isDisplayed)
}
```

A cleaner (preferred?) way is to check how many of these elements there are. You would have to change your getColumn method to:

```
public List<WebElement> getColumns() {
    return driver.findElements(column);
    // note the plural "findElements"
}
```

Then your test becomes just:

```
Assert.assertTrue("element is NOT displayed!",
    S.getColumns().size() > 0);
```