# Selenium Assert with existant and non-existent element

Tags: java, selenium, testng, assertion, webdriverwait

I have login form and I need to test it with correct and wrong credentials.

After putting login and password and then clicking on "Log In" button, web-site for 10 seconds it handling.

If credentials are Ok - mainPage.menu WebElement is displayed.

If credentials are wrong - mainPage.menu WebElement is not displayed.
Login page could be refreshed or (not always) error message could be shown.

How to check it in the tests?

For correct credentials, test works:

```
Assert.assertEquals(true, mainPage.menu.isDisplayed());
```

For wrong credentials, test fails with exception, because mainPage.menu could not be founded:

```
Assert.assertEquals(false, mainPage.menu.isDisplayed());
```

If I put in Assert "Log in" button, tests will always be successful, because in any case (any credentials) for first 10 seconds "Log in" is Displayed.
Of course, if I put Thread.sleep, it will solve a problem.
But, it's not a good practice.

Comment: Update the question with proper code trials

Comment: @DebanjanB, done!

Comment: This is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53838878/3124333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is here

```
Assert.assertEquals(false, mainPage.menu.isDisplayed());
```

when credentials are wrong then `mainPage.menu` will not be available right, which leads to exception. So need to handle this.Use `try/catch`

```
boolean displayed=false;

    try {
        mainPage.menu.isDisplayed();
        displayed=true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //element not displayed
        //displayed is false
    }

Assert.assertEquals(false, mainPage.menu.isDisplayed());
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this answer will cater to your requirement but ideally **valid** and **invalid** logins should be validated in seperate *testcases*. Additionally, avoid referencing items like **mainPage.menu** which are *true* incase of [False positives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives).

Ideal validation candidates can be:

- Valid Login: *Welcome Message*
- Invalid Login: *Error Message*

As per your usecase, you need to induce a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

```
try{
    Assert.assertEquals(true, <placeholder_of_welcome_message>.isDisplayed());
}catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, <placeholder_of_error_message>.isDisplayed()); 
}
```

Additionally, you may need to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows:

```
try{
    Assert.assertEquals(true, new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("welcome_message_element_id"))));
}catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("error_message_element_id")))); 
}
```